# By the time phrase and future simple. Possible?

Tags: future-tense, future-time, future-perfect

Which options are correct and why?

> I'll have had lots of money by tomorrow **or** I'll have lots of money
> by tomorrow?
>
> I'll be there by tomorrow **or** I'll have been there by tomorrow?
>
> I'll have finished the book by tomorrow **or** I'll finish the book by
> tomorrow?

This resource (https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/future-perfect-tense-use.html) demonstrates that you should you the future perfect tense with the **by the time** phrase, but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either, for example, both of these are correct:

- By this time tomorrow I **will have had** my dental work done.
- By this time tomorrow I **will have** my new teeth.

What makes your examples a bit weird-sounding is the specific subject matter, not the tense:

> I'll have had lots of money by tomorrow.

"Have had", as the present perfect tense, is best placed for use with events and experiences, such as "I have had a vacation" - the vacation was in the past, but you still possess that experience. When you use it to talk about money, it sounds more like you're saying you *did* possess money, but you don't any more.

You would be better saying "I'll *have* lots of money by tomorrow", or you could say "I'll have *received* a lot of money by tomorrow", which is more specifically about your receiving it and says nothing about whether you still possess it.

Comment: I might as well say "I'll have lots of money tomorrow"? Does "by tomorrow" add anything?

Comment: @Rusletov Yes it adds meaning. "I'll have lots of money tomorrow" could mean you are going to receive a large lump sum tomorrow. "I'll have lots of money **by** tomorrow" can indicate that you are receiving the money incrementally and it will have added up to a large amount by tomorrow; it could also mean that you've put something in motion today that will cause the money to come tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

*I'll have had lots of money* could mean that you will have got the money and lost it again! (This is because *I had money* implies that you don't have it any longer.) However, you could say, for example "I'll have earned lots of money by tomorrow".

Similarly, *I'll have been there by tomorrow* sounds as though you will have gone there and come back. You could say *I'll have got there by tomorrow.*